# How to prove the identity $(n-k)! \sum _{i=0}^{n-k} \frac{(k+i-1)!}{i!} = \frac{n!}{k}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, summation

I am stuck in proving the following :

$$(n-k)! \sum _{i=0}^{n-k} \frac{(k+i-1)!}{i!} = \frac{n!}{k}$$

NOTE: I don't want any combinatorial proof. I think it is some algebraic manipulation.

Comment: What have you tried?  I don't want to waste a bunch of time duplicating what you have already done, if your path just leads to a dead end...

Comment: Normally combinatorial proofs are considered better, this request is unusual.

Comment: It’s not correct. Try $n=2,k=1$: $$(2-1)!\left(\frac{0!}{0!}+\frac{1!}{1!}\right)=2\;,$$ not $\frac11=1$. The correct value is $\frac{n!}k$.

Comment: sorry everyone, I typed the RHS wrongly. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @vadim123, yes, some people insist on combinatorial proofs for some "cleanliness" consideration. I for one am very happy wallowing in the dirt ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s not quite correct:

$$\begin{align*}
(n-k)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\frac{(k+i-1)!}{i!}&=(n-k)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{k+i-1}i(k-1)!\\\\
&=(n-k)!(k-1)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{k+i-1}i\\\\
&=(n-k)!(k-1)!\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{k+i-1}{k-1}\\\\
&=(n-k)!(k-1)!\binom{n}k\\\\
&=\frac{(k-1)!n!}{k!}\\\\
&=\frac{n!}k
\end{align*}$$